# Flutter: Remove leading icon from expansion panel

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to remove this leading icon from expansion panel

[image: flu]

How can I do this?

Here is my code

```dart
    ExpansionPanelList(
            expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {},
            children: [
              ExpansionPanel(
    
                headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                  return Stack(children: [
                    ListTile(//and the rest of code...
```

Answer (score 19):

the only way to do it is by editing the ExpansionPanel source code.

I added a new property called hasIcon and set it by default to true
(to make sure it will not break the code).

```
    ExpansionPanel(
      hasIcon: false,       // <------
      canTapOnHeader: true,
      headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(
            'Title',
          ),
        );
      },
      body: Container(),    // <------
      isExpanded: false,    // <------
    ),
```

and here is how you edit the source code:

Press CTRL + click on ExpansionPanel widget,
then search for

```
this.isExpanded = false,
```

and add below it

```
this.isExpanded = false,
this.hasIcon = true,
```

then search for

```
final bool isExpanded;
```

and add below it

```
final bool isExpanded;
final bool hasIcon;
```

finally, search for

```
  Widget header = Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          duration: widget.animationDuration,
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          margin: _isChildExpanded(index) ? widget.expandedHeaderPadding : EdgeInsets.zero,
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: _kPanelHeaderCollapsedHeight),
            child: headerWidget,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      expandIconContainer,
    ],
  );
```

and replace it

```
  Widget header = Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          duration: widget.animationDuration,
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          margin: _isChildExpanded(index) ? widget.expandedHeaderPadding : EdgeInsets.zero,
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: _kPanelHeaderCollapsedHeight),
            child: headerWidget,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
          child: child.hasIcon? expandIconContainer:null,
      ),
    ],
  );
```

Comment: editing source code helps

Comment: Thank you works perfectly! Any idea how to hide the error message in vscode

Comment: This property doesn't exist on ExpansionPanel ```hasIcon: false```

Comment: its nice for me

Comment: No any property like hasIcon: false in ExpansionPanelList or ExpansionPanel.

Comment: (<--- flutter newbie) Is there a PR or issue for this to flutter? seems like something that should be in the main lib itself unless I'm misunderstanding the nature of this package

Answer (score 12):

This works,

Just add SizedBox.shrink() to the trailing properties of ExpansionTile

```
   ExpansionTile(
              trailing: SizedBox.shrink(),
              title: Text(
                "Title",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                ),
              ),
              children: <Widget>[
                ExpansionTile(
                  title: Text(
                    'Sub title',
                  ),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text('data'),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    'data'
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: actually i'm using exactly the expansion panel

Comment: It is elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can add [this file](https://gist.github.com/funyin/49315994ee78dce8d5f840c618e06f9a) to your code and use it in place of ExpansionPanelList.
Or You could edit the source code of ExpansionPanelList directly on your version of flutter (not recommended)

Answer (score 0):

[Modified](https://gist.github.com/iska9der/9a78b7bb7bc0d063d5f3f56e843057ae) versions of ExpansionPanelList and ExpansionPanel:

if you want to customize icon, you need to provide `iconBuilder` function to `ExpansionPanel`:

```
              iconBuilder: (child, isExpanded) {
                return ClipRRect(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  child: DecoratedBox(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: isExpanded
                          ? Colors.yellowAccent.withOpacity(.12)
                          : Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
                    ),
                    child: child,
                  ),
                );
              }
```

If you want to remove icon and gap, just return `null`:

```
              iconBuilder: (child, isExpanded) {
                return null;
              }
```

If you not provide iconBuilder, you'll see default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Since, Flutter have not still found a way to integrate this feature, I can suggest you just ctrl + click on the "ExapandablePanel" widget, go to source code page inside flutter sdk and copy the source code, after that follow these steps:

1. Create a new file, ex: custom_expandable_panel.dart.
2. Paste the copied source code and `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';` on top of this new class/file and remove other imports in the file.
3. Refactor/Rename the Class name/Widget name: ExapandablePanel to CustomExapandablePanel and Refactor/Rename: ExpansionPanelList to CustomExpansionPanelList and other things that you want. (Make sure to refactor and rename in all the place, best to use the right click refactor and rename provided by Android Studio, or anything similar in VS Code).
4. After that search for: "expandIconContainer" and comment that inside Widget header, children of Row Widget. Or you can even take a bool param to enable or disable the header icon.
5. You can comment any code or change things that you want, you are free to update and change the custom file as it is not directly a source file and only a clone of the source file and exist in different location.

Sample Code (If you want to add a bool flag in the custom file):

This can be your widget header inside the code:

```
Widget header = Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          duration: widget.animationDuration,
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          margin: _isChildExpanded(index) ? widget.expandedHeaderPadding : EdgeInsets.zero,
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: _kPanelHeaderCollapsedHeight),
            child: headerWidget,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      !!child.hasIcon ? expandIconContainer : Container(), //This
    ],
  );
```

Make sure to take the param inside:

```
CustomExpansionPanel({
required this.headerBuilder,
required this.body,
this.isExpanded = false,
this.canTapOnHeader = false,
this.hasIcon = false, //This
this.backgroundColor,
```

});

and add a variable for hasIcon just below somewhere as:

```
  /// Whether the panel is hasIcon.
  ///
  /// Defaults to false.
  final bool hasIcon; //This
```

and You can use this inside your flutter code (Where you want to use it) as:
import the custom_expansion_file on top of your code and use:

```
Widget get _bodyContainer {
return ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: AnyListYouHave?.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return CustomExpansionPanelList(
      elevation: 1,
      expandedHeaderPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      expansionCallback: (panelIndex, isExpanded) {
        setState(() {
          selectedIndex = index;
        });
      },
      children: [
        CustomExpansionPanel(
          hasIcon: false, //this
          canTapOnHeader: true,
          headerBuilder: (context, isExpanded) {
            return ListTile(
              tileColor: selectedIndex == index ? Colors.green : null,
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  selectedIndex = index;
                });
              },
              title: Text("Name"),
              leading: Checkbox(
                checkColor: Colors.green,
                activeColor: Colors.white,
                value: selectedIndex == index,
                onChanged: (isChecked) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedIndex = index;
                  });
                },
              ),
              // You can uncomment this (trailing) to use your custom widget for dropdown
              // trailing: isExpanded ? null : IconButton(
              //   icon: Icon(
              //     isExpanded ? Icons.arrow_drop_up : Icons.arrow_drop_down,
              //   ),
              //   onPressed: () {
              //     setState(() {
              //       selectedIndex = index;
              //     });
              //   },
              // ),
            );
          },
          body: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text('Any Text'),
                SizedBox(height: 8),
                Text('Any Text'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          isExpanded: selectedIndex == index,
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);
```

}

Thanks and Please free to suggest any modifications or better alternatives than editing source code or using any other packages or options.

Answer (score 0):

```
ExpansionTile(
    trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_right_outlined),
          // Or
    trailing: SizedBox()
)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `ExpantionTile` inside the panel, you can provide `trailing` widget to it which will replace the arrow.

There is an ongoing effort in adding this feature to `ExpansionPanel`, but that is moment, it is not supported.
You can extend this and customize or other libraries  which provide this feature. (The one mentioned by @bensal)

Comment: no , in fact i'm using expansion panel list and inside of that i used expansion panel

Comment: Please share the code. ExpansionPanel might also have a trailing property

Comment: use expanded panel plugin, it has lot more options and you can easily disable icon. https://pub.dev/packages/expandable

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue with ExpandablePanel, I created an ExpandableThemeData and set the hasIcon property to false.

```
var themeData = ExpandableThemeData(hasIcon: false);
ExpandablePanel(
    theme: themeDate,
    ... rest of the code...
      )
```

Answer (score -1):

So, I realize this is an older question, but I spent awhile looking for a good answer. Since Version 4.0 introduced themes to expandable widgets, and you can use `hasIcon` to remove the header icon.

```
          ExpansionPanel(
            theme:  const ExpandableThemeData(
             hasIcon: false, // <--- Disables icon
            ),
            headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
              return Stack(children: [
                ListTile(//and the rest of code...
```

check out https://pub.dev/documentation/expandable/latest/

Comment: Although not wrong, this is for the Expandable package. The problem and question has to do with `ExpansionPanel` in base Flutter